# How to programtically set a suitable padding for matplotlib colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm creating some subplots each with its own colorbar at the bottom. The colorbar is added using:

```
cax, kw = mcbar.make_axes_gridspec(ax, orientation='horizontal',
                                   pad=pad,
                                   fraction=0.07, shrink=0.85, aspect=35)
figure.colorbar(cs, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
```

The `pad` argument is adjusted, so that if there is no xticklabels, the value is smaller, to avoid wasting space.

The complete script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar as mcbar

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2+np.sin(Y)

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
nrow = 3
ncol = 2

for ii in range(nrow*ncol):
    ax = figure.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, ii+1)
    row, col = np.unravel_index(ii, (nrow, ncol))

    cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
    if row == nrow-1:
        # larger padding to make room for xticklabels
        pad = 0.15
    else:
        # smaller padding otherwise
        pad = 0.05
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

    if row == 1 and col == 1:
        # add xlabel would need more padding
        ax.set_xlabel('X')

    cax, kw = mcbar.make_axes_gridspec(ax, orientation='horizontal',
                                       pad=pad,
                                       fraction=0.07, shrink=0.85, aspect=35)
    figure.colorbar(cs, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
    ax.set_title(str(ii+1))

figure.tight_layout()
figure.show()
```

The output figure:

[image]

But the current solution is using hard-coded padding values (`0.15` if with `xticklabels`, `0.05` otherwise), and it doesn't adjust well to the existence of `xlabels` (see subplot 4), or changing figure sizes.

Is there a way to programmatically work out a suitable padding value to place the colorbar? Maybe by adjusting the bounding box of the parent axis object so that its bbox is smaller if there is no `xlabels` or `xticklabels`, or by finding out the coordinates of the parent axis and somehow computing a padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the space needed for tick labels and the axis label by comparing the bounding boxes of the whole axes and the yaxis. To get these bounding boxes we need a renderer. To make it available we first need to draw the canvas. The bounding boxes are returned in display coordinates, so we transform them to axes coordinates using the inverted axes transformation. The difference of their y coordinates gives the required extra padding:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar as mcbar
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2+np.sin(Y)

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
figure.canvas.draw()  # to get renderer
nrow = 3
ncol = 2

for ii in range(nrow*ncol):
    ax = figure.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, ii+1)
    row, col = np.unravel_index(ii, (nrow, ncol))

    cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
    if row != nrow-1:
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

    if row == 1 and col == 1:
        # add xlabel would need more padding
        ax.set_xlabel('X')

    # get height of ticklabels and label
    b = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(
        [ax.yaxis.get_tightbbox(figure.canvas.renderer).p0,
        ax.get_tightbbox(figure.canvas.renderer).p0]
    )
    pad = 0.05 + (b[0]-b[1])[1]

    cax, kw = mcbar.make_axes_gridspec(ax, orientation='horizontal',
                                       pad=pad,
                                       fraction=0.07, shrink=0.85, aspect=35)
    figure.colorbar(cs, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
    ax.set_title(str(ii+1))
```

[image]

This solution has the flaw that axes 3 and 4 have different heights. You can fix this by adjusting `ymin` of all axes in a row to the row maximum:

```
figure.tight_layout()
for i in range(0, 2*ncol*nrow, 2*ncol):
    ymin = 0
    for j in range(0, 2*ncol, 2):
        ymin = max(ymin, figure.axes[i+j].get_position().ymin)
    for j in range(0, 2*ncol, 2):
        b = figure.axes[i+j].get_position()
        figure.axes[i+j].set_position(Bbox([[b.xmin,ymin],[b.xmax,b.ymax]]))
```

Please note that this adjustment **must be done before applying `tight_layout`**!
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent many hours trying to solve this but in vain. This really helps. After some tests I made 2 minor changes based on your solution: 1) `renderer = figure.canvas.get_renderer()` and `ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)`  seem to work, not sure any difference behind the scene; 2) It seems that `ax.patch.get_extents().p0` is more robust than `ax.yaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer).p0`. Sometimes when I set larger font sizes for the ticklabels, the `ax.yaxis.get_tightbbox().p0` way still gives overlaps of the colorbar and ticklabels.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes, get_renderer is better as it creates a new one if it can't reuse an existing. I'm not sure about the second change but if it works for you it's fine. So I guess you can accept the answer.

Comment: Sure. I added another change: temporally set `ax.set_aspect('auto')` before obtaining the renderer and computing the `pad`, then restore the aspect to the original `ax.set_aspect(old_aspect)` afterwards.